# A visual studio macro to format code comma first

Tags: visual-studio, macros

I'm trying to use the Visual Studio Macro Editor

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d3fbf133-e51b-41a2-b86f-9560a96ff62b

which allows the user to write macros in javascript to drive the IDE. What I'd like to be able to do is write a macro that formats the text

```
public void Foo(
int i,
int b,
int c)
```

to

```
public void Foo
( int i
, int b
, int c
)
```

This should be quite trivial if I only knew the commands to do the following.

```
(1) Move the cursor to the next matching character, and detect if it is not found
(2) Insert a carriage return
(3) Join lines together
```

I have got as far as

```
dte.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Find");
dte.Find.FindWhat = ",";
```

but was hoping somebody might know their DTE commands better than I.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Move the cursor to the next matching character, and detect if it is not found:

```
DTE.Find.FindWhat = ",";
DTE.Find.Target = EnvDTE.vsFindTarget.vsFindTargetCurrentDocument;
if (DTE.Find.Execute() == EnvDTE.vsFindResult.vsFindResultNotFound)
{
// not found
}
```

(2) Insert a carriage return:

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.BreakLine");
```

(3) Join lines together:

`Edit.DeleteBackwards` or `Edit.Delete` can delete a line break when called from the beginning or from the end of a line.

(Note: This is syntax from my Visual Commander extension, but should work for Visual Studio Macro Editor as well.)